# WCF deserialize messages from MSMQ

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, msmq

I have a scenario where we will be getting 10-15 different XML messages enqueued to a message queue.  All of the examples I have found depicting messages via WCF from an Queue show using "typeof - object" to deserialize the message.  However, in our case we will have a lot of different messages residing i the queue so simply trying to set a specific type won't work.  How are others handling a similar type of scenario where there are numerous types of messages?

Each message will have a `<MessageHeader>` and a `<MessageBody>`, but inside the body the payloads will be different for each message type.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WCF `MsmqIntegrationBinding` and handle messages of type `MsmqMessage<string>`. Then your handler method will receive the serialized message as a string and can do what you want with it after that.